# MySQL CTE not referenced in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, common-table-expression

I am having trouble understanding why a `CTE` can't be referenced from a `WHERE` clause.
In the following code, the first query works fine, but in the second query, simply replacing the value in the `WHERE` clause with a CTE which calculates that value, produces the error "Unknown column 'cte' in 'where clause'".

```
# This query works

SELECT * FROM stock_prices
WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Stock_Code IN ('1332');


# But this query produces an error

WITH
    cte AS (SELECT '1332')    
SELECT * FROM stock_prices
WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Stock_Code IN (cte);


# Here is some data to test these two queries with

CREATE TABLE stock_prices (Country_Exchange_Code VARCHAR(2), Stock_Code VARCHAR(4), Date DATE, Close FLOAT);
INSERT INTO stock_prices VALUES
("T", "1301",   '2019-10-29',   75.2),
("T", "1301",   '2019-10-30',   76.6),
("T", "1301",   '2019-10-31',   77.6),
("T", "1301",   '2019-11-01',   77.2),
("T", "1332",   '2019-10-29',   52.5),
("T", "1332",   '2019-10-30',   49.7),
("T", "1332",   '2019-10-31',   50.8),
("T", "1332",   '2019-11-01',   50.4),
("T", "1333",   '2019-10-29',   13.9),
("T", "1333",   '2019-10-30',   13.8),
("T", "1333",   '2019-10-31',   14.3),
("T", "1333",   '2019-11-01',   14.4);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may refer to `cte` or another table by the name (not using a subselect from it) using `TABLE` keyword.

```
WITH
    cte AS (SELECT '1332')    
SELECT * FROM stock_prices
WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Stock_Code IN (TABLE cte);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a76745976d8bb9766ab08b9d2aaa67f)

Comment: Just a sidenote `TABLE cte` is a syntactic sugar for `SELECT * FROM cte` and it works in this scenario because cte returns only single column

Comment: @LukaszSzozda *is a syntactic sugar for* How do you think, why [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table.html) tells "acts like", "produces identical output" and so on, but do NOT say "is an alias"? *it works in this scenario because cte returns only single column* Nothing prevents use it in multi-column scenario: `WHERE (column1, ..., columnX) IN (TABLE cte)` - the only restriction is in the same columns amount, order and datatype.

Comment: I don't understand why you may think my comment was going to undermine your answer in any way. In any case I wrote *syntactic sugar* because I know that construct from [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html): `The command

TABLE name

is equivalent to

SELECT * FROM name`. Second comment about multiple columns was refering differnent scenario when cte query returns more than one column and you need to use one from cte. I.e: `WITH cte AS (SELECT 123, 456) SELECT * FROM tab WHERE Stock_Code IN (TABLE cte)` won't work.

Comment: I thought it should work with `(TABLE cte)`! But this is weird. I copy pasted your code block there and I get a syntax error. Take out the word `TABLE` and no syntax error. Using MySQL 8.0.17.

Comment: @FinGeek *Using MySQL 8.0.17* This is info which must be posted firstly. For this version a subselect is [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63363901/10138734).

Comment: @LukaszSzozda *I don't understand why you may think my comment was going to undermine your answer in any way.* I don't think so. But I think that TABLE statement is NOT mapped to SELECT * FROM directly. I think that SELECT has a lot of additional overhead - if not then TABLE statement existence makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Akina Agreed I should have put the version up there. I just thought a recent version like 8.0.xx should be assumed. Any ideas why your Fiddle code block produces a syntax error when I put it into Workbench? Fiddle is running 8.0 so there shouldn't be much difference from 8.0.17.

Comment: @FinGeek *Any ideas why your Fiddle code block produces a syntax error when I put it into Workbench?* I think this is old WB version which doesn't know about 8+ version features... PS. I do not use smart GUIs which tries to parse my queries.

Comment: I got the same syntax error in the Command line Client as well, so it wasn't a Workbench issue. So then out of curiosity I upgraded MySQL Server from 8.0.17 to the very latest 8.0.21. Syntax error disappeared! Must have been a bug in all the minor releases up until now.

Comment: Lots of good answers here. But this one fixed my error by adding only one word `TABLE` to my original code block. So I think it is the best answer to my question. Just don't try this solution if your table is more than one column!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are thinking of a cte as some kind of variable instead of thinking of it as a virtual table.

You can't do `IN (cte)` just like you can't do `IN (sometablename)`; it needs to be `IN (select somecol from sometablename)`.

Comment: In my actual code 'cte' is a table that contains hundreds of stock codes. I just simplified the example to the extreme. I get the same error in all cases.

Comment: right.  but the problem is you are using it as if it were a variable; to use IN with the values from a table or cte, you need to explicitly select them

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
WITH
    cte AS (SELECT '1332' as code)    
SELECT * FROM stock_prices
WHERE Country_Exchange_Code = 'T' AND Stock_Code IN (select code from cte);
```

Result:

```
 Country_Exchange_Code  Stock_Code  Date        Close 
 ---------------------- ----------- ----------- ----- 
 T                      1332        2019-10-29  52.5  
 T                      1332        2019-10-30  49.7  
 T                      1332        2019-10-31  50.8  
 T                      1332        2019-11-01  50.4
```

Your query had two issues:

- `IN` requires a formal subquery with the form `SELECT ...`
- The cte needed named columns; that why I added `as code`.

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/97jVWwKkvs4j2aHw5LeyDx/0).

Comment: So the problem was primarily with my use of the `IN` operator rather than the `CTE`. I was aware that you can use `IN` with subqueries in the form of `IN(TABLE tablename)` as long as the table contains only a single column (which it does here).  So why doesn't changing the last line to `Stock_Code IN (TABLE cte)` work?

Comment: `IN (TABLE cte)` works too. It's a non-standard SQL extension implemented by MySQL.